Simulation of a a simple vehicle with given engine power
I want to write a simple Javascript simulation of a vehicle moving horizontally in a straight line, with drag $F_\mathrm{drag} = -kv$. The engine power is $P_\mathrm{engine}$ (which can be negative) and is adjustable through a slider.
The purpose is to illustrate that the "acceleration pedal" (gas pedal) does not control acceleration; and that an actual acceleration pedal, were one to build such a thing, would work completely differently (and would be pretty useless).
I intend to first try a very simple Euler solver based on y += y'*dt, with dt measured between frames.
My first attempt at writing the physical equations was this:
let Pengine = 0;
let Fengine = 0;
let Fdrag = 0; // -k*v, always opposed to v
let Facc = 0; // Fengine + Fdrag = Facc (the net force actually accelerating the vehicle)
let a = 0;
let v = 0;
let x = 0;
let Ek = 0; // kinetic energy

function gas_pedal(P) {
    Pengine = P;
    Fengine = Pengine/v;
    Fdrag = -k*v;
    Facc = Fengine + Fdrag;
    a = Facc/m;
    v += a*dt;
    x += v*dt;
    Ek = m/2*v*v;
}

The problem is that Fengine = Pengine/v spikes to infinity at very low speeds. This is unavoidable when the vehicle brakes (negative Pengine, suppose it's an electric motor with recuperative braking) and changes direction -- then the velocity v can become exactly 0.
My second attempt is based on kinetic energy (the energy delivered by the engine is split between overcoming drag and changing the vehicle's kinetic energy):
function gas_pedal_kinetic(P) {
    Pengine = P;
    let direction = v < 0 ? -1 : 1; // not Math.abs(v), because I don't want it to be 0 when v = 0
    let dEk_dt = direction*Math.abs(Pengine) + Fdrag*v;
    Ek += dEk_dt*dt;
    let v_old = v;
    v = direction*Math.sqrt(2/m*Ek);
    a = (v - v_old)/dt;
    x += v*dt;
    Facc = m*a;
    Fdrag = -k*v;
    Fengine = Facc - Fdrag;
}

(This is a simplified version, I had to take care not to get negative kinetic energy; and to reverse direction when the vehicle stops. But that is a detail, I skipped it here for the sake of clarity.)
My question is: Is this approach OK from the physical standpoint? If not, how else would you advise me to write the equations in order to avoid the "infinite force when reversing direction" problem?

The first attempt is reasonable but I am not sure your modeling of the engine force actually makes sense. A car maneuvering should not maintain a constant power, but that is what you are encoding in your dynamics and this is what leads to the issues when the speed of the car is small. From my view, your car engine could more realistically generate some constant torque on the front tires, perhaps a torque chosen on the slider, and you can then compute the force from that using various info about the car, like car tire specs, weight of car, etc.

@spektr Thank you for the comment. I forgot to mention that (for now) I consider the road smooth and uniform (no different sections like asphalt, sand, mud etc.). I.e., kdrag is constant. The only varying thing is how much the driver's foot presses on the gas pedal. So you're saying that the gas pedal controls torque, not engine power. This would make my calculations go smooth, I guess, but I'm afraid that my simulation won't be that convincing, because people might object "It's gas pedal, not torque pedal". As far as I know, the gas pedal controls how much fuel goes into the engine -> power.

I think this depends on the type of engine. For an internal combustion engine, the throttle modifies the torque, which is then multiplied by RPMs to obtain power. The problem with ICEs is that the torque the engine can output varies a lot over the RPM range, necessitating different gear ratios

@whpowell96 Very insightful comment. You made me think and I realized that indeed the gas pedal of an ICE does not control power. At least not directly. It controls the work per cycle, which then gets multiplied by cycles per second to determine power. I'm wondering, for an electric motor, what does the "speed regulator" control? It can't be speed (because that depends on the load), so is it torque (force), power or something else? Is there such a thing as "power regulator"? For some kind of motor. I mean, direct power regulator, not through a control loop (e.g., a PID controller).

I believe that electric motors also directly influence the torque. By increasing the electric current flowing through a loop in a magnetic field, it increases the torque on the rotating shaft in the center of the loop. I do not know much more about them but I( believe you should be able to find some torque/power curves for electric motors that you can apply to your model

Yes, after a good night sleep things became clear to me: an ICE's pedal controls the power per cycle, which gets multiplied by RPM to get the total power. But power = torque x RPM, so what the "gas pedal" really controls is torque. Or, in linear terms, force. The same for electric motors, as you argued. So my assumption that the "gas pedal" controls power is wrong, at least for combustion engines and electric motors. I'm beginning to think that a power regulator is impossible in practice, precisely because it would lead to infinite force (when the vehicle is at rest), as in my model.

Thank you @whpowell96, your comments helped me understand a lot of things.
